# How to run Web Application using console application?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, web-applications, console-application, publish

My lecturer gave me task to do in the web application. However, he wants me to send him .exe file because he doesn't have a VisualStudio on his PC.
I found on Internet an idea to run web application by console application, becouse console application can be published to .exe file. But have no idea, and didnt find how to do it.
Many guides show how to run it on localhost, but they start it from Visual Studio run button, i need .exe file to zip and send to my teacher :/
Its my app here (.NET 6.0, mvc WebApplication). https://github.com/Arachnacein/Mio
Its small application just to implement genetics alghorithm for laboratories. It dont have any database and actually I start it by my Visual Studio run button.
I did research but didn't find any helpful materials.
Thanks for all the help and helpful links.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core app is a console application. If you want you can use single file deployment which will allow to bundle everything into single file:

- [Single-file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)

Which also can be done via [VS UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs) by creating reusable publishing profile:

1. Add `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` to your project file.
2. On the **Solution Explorer** pane, right-click on the project you want to publish. Select **Publish**.

   [image: :::image type="content" source="../media/single-file/visual-studio-solution-explorer.png" alt-text="Screenshot shows Solution Explorer with a context menu highlighting the Publish option.":::]

   If you don't already have a publishing profile, follow the instructions to create one and choose the **Folder** target-type.
3. Choose **Edit**.

   [image]
4. In the **Profile settings** dialog, set the following options:

   - Set **Deployment mode** to **Self-contained** or **Framework-dependent**.
   - Set **Target runtime** to the platform you want to publish to. Must be something other than **Portable**.
   - Select **Produce single file**.

   Choose **Save** to save the settings and return to the **Publish** dialog.

   [image: :::image type="content" source="../media/single-file/visual-studio-publish-single-file-properties.png" alt-text="Screenshot shows Profile settings dialog with Deployment mode, Target runtime, and Produce single file options highlighted.":::]
5. Choose **Publish** to publish your app as a single file.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Which way can i run my web application using this console app?

Comment: @JakubŁuka You just run the generated file.

Comment: I need to run it programmatically

Comment: @JakubŁuka your web application IS a console app. You just publish it as a single file and send to your lecturer to run.

Comment: Do i understand it correct? In one solution i need to have console application and web application? And in single (published) file will be included 2 apps?

Comment: @JakubŁuka no. You just publish your web app as single file and that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253264/discussion-between-jakub-luka-and-guru-stron).